# Is there a way to get UID in pod spec

Tags: kubernetes

What I want to do is providing pod with unified log store, currently persisted to hostPath, but I also want this path including UID so I can easily get its path after pod destroyed.

For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-with-logging-support
spec:
  containers:
  - image: python:2.7
    name: web-server
    command:
    - "sh"
    - "-c"
    - "python -m SimpleHTTPServer > /logs/http.log 2>&1"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /logs
      name: log-dir
  volumes:
  - name: log-dir
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log/apps/{metadata.uid}
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

`metadata.uid` is what I want to fill in, but I do not how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

For logging it's better to use another strategy.

I suggest you to look at this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/).

Your logs are best managed if streamed to stdout and grabbed by an agent, like shown in this picture:

[image]

Don't persist your log on filesystem, but gather them using an agent and put them together for further analysis.

[Fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/) is very popular and deserves to be known.

Comment: I was aware of this. But this requires a fluentd which is a complexity we want to avoid. We want the simplest solution for persist log for later review

Answer (score 1):

After searching the doc from kubernetes, I finally see a [solution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath-with-expanded-environment-variables) for my specific problem. This feature is exactly what I wanted.

So I can create the pod with

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-with-logging-support
spec:
  containers:
  - image: python:2.7
    name: web-server
    command:
    - "sh"
    - "-c"
    - "python -m SimpleHTTPServer > /logs/http.log 2>&1"
    env:
    - name: POD_UID
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.uid
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /logs
      name: log-dir
      subPath: $(POD_UID)
  volumes:
  - name: log-dir
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log/apps/
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
```